# What is the polymer "is" property?

Tags: polymer

I am new to polymer and keep seeing the "is" property, but never get a thorough explanation of it.  Example :

```
<script>
   Polymer({is: "some-property"})
</script>
```

or

```
<template is="dom-repeat"></template>
```

It seems to be a declaration of inheritance or the like and i sorta get it but would like to find a clear explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements):

> To register a custom element, use the Polymer function, and pass in
>   the prototype for the new element. The prototype must have an **is**
>   property that specifies the HTML tag name for your custom element.

In this case, the

```
<template is="dom-repeat"></template>
```

is a specific custom element built-in to Polymer.js, which extends the native HTML `template` element.

Comment: Could you please explain the template "is" attribute?  Is it related?

Comment: The template repeater is a specific instance of a custom element. See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates